# Error showing when call a function from method in $root.on in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I need to call a method when dropdown value changes. Dropdown is in completely separate component from where i want to call a method. So i am using $root.

Trading.vue

```
<v-autocomplete
  label="Entity"
  v-model="tradingAs"
  :items="getTradeEntities"
  item-value="id"
  item-text="entity"
  hide-details
  return-object
  @change="tradeChange"
/>

tradeChange(){
  this.$root.$emit('trade_as_event', this.tradingAs.id)
}
```

New.vue

```
data: () => ({
  tradeAsAccount: null
}),

mounted: function(){
  this.$root.$on('trade_as_event', function(data) {
    this.tradeAsAccount = data
    console.log(this.tradeAsAccount)
    this.createQuoteConfig() //this line gives error
  })
},

methods: {
  createQuoteConfig() {
    console.log('call api with updated id', this.tradeAsAccount)
  }
}
```

Error:
Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "trade_as_event": "TypeError: this.createQuoteConfig is not a function"

(found in )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in the anonymous function does **not** point to instance of current component. Actually it points to the $root.

```js
mounted: function() {
  const root = this.$root
  this.$root.$on('trade_as_event', function(data) {
    console.log(this===root); // true
  })
}
```

There are two ways to solve the problem.

##### Option one: Arrow Function

In [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), this retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's this.

```js
this.$root.$on('trade_as_event', (data) => {
  this.tradeAsAccount = data
  console.log(this.tradeAsAccount)
  this.createQuoteConfig()
})
```

##### Option two: Vue methods

All methods declared in Vue options will have their this context automatically bound to the Vue instance.

```js
data: () => ({
  tradeAsAccount: null
}),

mounted: function(){
  this.$root.$on('trade_as_event', this.handleTradeAsEvent)
},

methods: {
  handleTradeAsEvent(data) {
    this.tradeAsAccount = data
    console.log(this.tradeAsAccount)
    this.createQuoteConfig()
  },
  createQuoteConfig() {
    console.log('call api with updated id', this.tradeAsAccount)
  }
}
```